# What is the location of the MODULE_PATHNAME in Apache Age?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

While `$libdir` is commonly used when creating PostgreSQL extensions, Apache Age utilizes the `MODULE_PATHNAME` variable to store and retrieve compiled C code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ag_catalog.create_graph(graph_name name)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE c
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME';
```

This variable is declared in the `age.control` file as follows:

```
default_version = '1.2.0'
comment = 'AGE database extension'
module_pathname = '$libdir/age'
```

However, I could not find a folder named `age` in `$libdir` (i.e., `$libdir/age`).

Comment: Okay, it could be that `age` in `$libdir/age` is not actually a folder, but instead a shared library file named `age.so`. This would make sense, given that `$libdir` is typically the directory where PostgreSQL shared libraries are stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the `lib` directory where you have installed PostgreSQL as a file named `age.so`. The path you have installed PostgreSQL is specified when you used the `./configure --prefix={path}` command during the installation process. It is commonly stored in `/usr/local/` but that will depend on where you have specified the path to be.

[image: Screenshot]